# Hartshorne Exercise V.2.2

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This exercise is to prove a ruled surface $X=\mathbf{P}(\mathscr E)$ over a curve $C$ is decomposable if and only if there exist two sections $C'$ and $C''$ of $X$ such that $C'\cap C'' = \emptyset$. Here $\mathscr E$ is a locally free sheaf of rank $2$ on $C$ and can be regarded normalized. Also $X$ and $C$ are defined over a certain algebraically closed field and $\mathbf{P}(\mathscr E)$ means the projective space bundle.

I have some trouble in proving the "if" part, i.e. suppose there are two sections $C'$ and $C''$ of $X$ such that $C'\cap C'' = \emptyset$, then $X$ is decomposable.  Can anybody give me some hints or solutions? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe something like this: if these two sections exist, then they define distinct points in every fiber of $P(E)$, which correspond to distinct lines in the fiber of $E$. Now has to see that these lines form sub-line bundles, which do not intersect, because the sections do not intersect. But then $E$ must be the direct sum of these line bundles.

Comment: @Bernie  Thank you for your reply.  But the point is here as you pointed out:  how to see these lines form sub-line bundles.

Comment: Here you can find an idea how to prove it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293816/classification-of-3-pointed-rational-curves